# Why are there three directories/folders for the java source in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to Android development. When I created a new Android Studio project there are three directories generated inside the `java` section:

[image]

In fact our concern is with the java file that is inside the first directory which is in my case `com.example.myapplication -> MainActivity`.

Why are there three directories each containing java files and for what purpose are these directories created?

Comment: As name implies they hold source code for tests. Read up on official docs https://developer.android.com/studio/projects#ProjectView

Comment: What is meant by testing in this sense? We are already testing the application during development.

Comment: But are you testing to make sure that your new changes don't break something else that was already working?

Comment: No i am not testing but i was confused about these directories. So its better to clear the concept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to wikipedia, development testing is a software development process that involves synchronized application of a broad spectrum of defect prevention and detection strategies in order to reduce software development risks, time, and costs, [see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Development_testing).

**Folders:**
*First* (`com.example.myapplication`) for actual source code. For example, java/kotlin files of activities, services, broadcast receivers, content providers, models, utilities etc.

*Second* (`com.example.myapplication(andoridTest)`) is for [*instrumental testing*](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests) that runs on android OS. As an example, assume that we have `MainActivity` with a button. Toast with a message is shown when the button is clicked. So we can test whether the button works correctly as following(imports are provided for simplicity):

```
import androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner;
import androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static androidx.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.RootMatchers.withDecorView;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.isDisplayed;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.not;

import static androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class ExampleAndroidTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<Main2Activity> mActivityRule =
            new ActivityTestRule<>(Main2Activity.class);

    @Test
    public void buttonClickShowingToast_isCorrect() {
        onView(withId(R.id.bt_test)).perform(click());
        onView(withText(R.string.toast_test))
            .inRoot(withDecorView(not(
                    mActivityRule.getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView()
            ))).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
}
}
```

*Third* (`com.example.myapplication(test)`) is for [*Unit tests*](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing) that can be run on local machine, means doesn't require android OS. For example, we are creating a timer and we have an utility method that converts seconds to HH:MM:SS format. The method is:

```
public static String getHoursMinutesSeconds(int seconds) {
    int minutes = seconds / 60;
    seconds %= 60;
    int hours = minutes / 60;
    minutes %= 60;

    String strSec = Integer.toString(seconds);
    String strMin = Integer.toString(minutes);
    String strHour = Integer.toString(hours);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (strHour.length() < 2) sb.append(0);
    sb.append(strHour);
    sb.append(':');
    if (strMin.length() < 2) sb.append(0);
    sb.append(strMin);
    sb.append(':');
    if (strSec.length() < 2) sb.append(0);
    sb.append(strSec);

    return sb.toString();
}
```

As the method doesn't require *Android APIs* to be tested. It has to be tested on local machine(as it is much faster). So the Unit tests code:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner;

import io.jachoteam.taxiapp.views.WaitingIndicatorView;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;

@RunWith(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class ExampleUnitTest {

    @Test
    public void getHoursMinutesSeconds_isCorrect1() {
        String actualValue = WaitingIndicatorView.getHoursMinutesSeconds(1);
        assertThat(actualValue, is(equalTo("00:00:01")));
    }

    @Test
    public void getHoursMinutesSeconds_isCorrect2() {
        String actualValue = WaitingIndicatorView.getHoursMinutesSeconds(60);
        assertThat(actualValue, is(equalTo("00:01:00")));
    }
}
```

Writing tests for each written unit of code is *the best practice*. Cause it makes developer's life easier when a project gets big to maintain by providing bug detecting in early stages(while fresh=)) and validating the code every time it has been changed.

Comment: I am ok about the first two but the third one `unit test` is confusing. What it is basically? Can you please provide an example with each `First`, `Second` and `Third` so your answer will be more clear.

Comment: @SunnyKhan A search for "unit test" will provide a lifetime's worth of reading.

Comment: I have added examples also @SunnyKhan

Answer (score 1):

Per the [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects#ProjectView):

**/test:**
Contains code for local tests that run on your host JVM.

**/androidtest**
Instrumentation tests, run on the OS.

**/module-name:**
This is where the program source code lives